How to transform a variable value before passing to a query in Grafana
I have a multi-select variable in Grafana, which gives me names of applications comma separated (app1,app2,app3). I am using Wavefront as datasource and Wavefront Query Language. I would like to get metrics for all those applications selected. The only way I could figure out so far to get metrics out is by passing application names separately with "OR" clause in WQL.
Example:
(application=app1 OR application=app2 OR  application=app3)
Is there any way to convert (app1,app2,app3)  to (application=app1 OR application=app2 OR  application=app3) using Grafana variable interpolation or some other sort?

An example in the documentation helped to create correct format - wavefront query language reference.
application=/(${app|pipe})/

It looks like you need advance formatting. I guess lucene syntax for your variable in the query.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/variable-syntax/#lucene---elasticsearch

Thank you! syntax helped me investigate in the right direction. Needed to use pipe
